# Show modal first in JS before performing other functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a question and was wondering if I am doing something wrong.

I have a page which is got close to 200 div's.

So when i run the function, basically it hides all the 200 divs first and then shows particular divs. This is already happening. but since it is hiding all 200 divs first and then showing 10-15 divs [based on operator logic], it is taking 5-7 seconds.

I was looking to show a pop-up modal as soon as the function starts, then the looping of divs to hide them.. and then the function to show the divs that needs to be shown and finally hide the pop-up modal.

But when I run the function, the modal hardly comes as it waits for the whole loop to finish.

I am using the following:

```
function show_by_price()
{
    $('#loading').modal('show');

    for(j=1; j<= $("#total_div_count").val(); j++)
    {
       $("#div_id_"+j).hide()
    }

    $('#loading').modal('hide');
}
```

Comment: `the modal hardly comes as it waits for the whole loop to finish` what do you mean by that?

Comment: Why using a loop for all IDs? Can't you use a common class for that? Or using the *attribute starts with* selector with

Comment: Why are you showing the modal and then hiding it again immediately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't understand the problem with the modal but I have another question -

Why don't you have 2 divs, one main container for all the 200 elements and another "help" container. So when you need to do the hiding - you hide the main container instead of hiding 200 elements one by one and then move the desired 10-15 elements that should be shown in the second help container which is visible?

This should be much better performance-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do all this with JavaScript, there is a much more efficient way to show/hide elements as suggested by [Samuil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42092400/954940). That being said, you may be interested in looking into doing something based on [bootstrap modal events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events).

```
$('#loading').on('shown.bs.modal',function() {
   //execute code in here after the modal is fully visible
}).modal('show');
```